# Face writing wrong

Tags: export

I tried export with other includes can't think of anything more

It exports faces like so:

f 65//37 59//37 63//37

But the exported faces should look like this:

f 85/397/131 89/402/136 90/406/140

Comment: so what are you asking?

Comment: What exactly is writing the faces?

Comment: What are you asking?

Comment: Check the OBJ spec, this is in fact correct.

Answer (score 3):

When you try to export object to .obj file format (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavefront_.obj_file), then exporter has several options:

[image: Blender OBJ export options]

One option is "Write Normals". When you will have mesh UV unwrapped too, then it will be exported in expected variant of obj file format. Double slash is there for compatibility with some other application (Rhino?).